# Integrating the Blend design into Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, blend

I am a student & am newly introduced to the Microsoft Blend.
Its something really impressive & makes me design happily.
But I am facing a problem: Its fine about the designing part but what about the coding?
Where are we suppose to write the code? I mean how are we to import that file into Visual Studio 2010.

Please do tell me the solution ? I have been looking out for resources nearly everyday.
But its still in vague.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Expression Blend is a tool meant for designers so it does not really focus much on features for writing code. It is actually designed to inter-operate well with Visual Studio and you should be able to just open any Blend project or solution in Visual Studio and do your coding there.

In fact, I often have both tools open at the same time with the same project open and it makes for a pretty smooth workflow. For example, if I make a change in Blend and then switch to Visual Studio it will prompt me to reload the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio installed the easiest way is to click on a file inside the Projects tab and then choose Edit in Visual Studio (see image). Once you do that VS will load the project / solution and open the file for you to edit your file and or add code to it.

[image: Blend Open in VS Menu]